# error in python program. "expected 2D array but got 1D array instead"

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to predict the price as well as plot to visualize the data. But there is an error that I am not able to figure it out.

```
dates=[]
prices=[]

def getdata(filename):
    with open(filename,'r') as csvfile:
        csvFilereader=csv.reader(csvfile)
        next(csvFilereader)
        for row in csvFilereader:

            dates.append(int(row[0].split('-')[0]))
            prices.append(float(row[1]))
    return
def predicted_price(dates, prices, x):

    dates=np.reshape(dates,len(dates),1)


    svr_linear= SVR(kernel='linear', C=1e3)
    svr_poly= SVR(kernel='poly', C=1e3, degree=2)
    svr_rbf= SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, gamma=0.1)

    svr_linear.fit(dates,prices)
    svr_poly.fit(dates,prices)
    svr_rbf.fit(dates,prices)

    plt.scatter(dates,prices, color='black', label='Data')
    plt.plot(dates, svr.rbf.predict(dates), color='red', label='RBF Model')
    plt.plot(dates, svr.poly.predict(dates), color='blue', label='Poly Model')
    plt.plot(dates, svr.linear.predict(dates), color='green', label='Linera Model')

    plt.xlabel('Dates')
    plt.ylabel('Prices')
    plt.title('Regression')

    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

    return svr_rbf.predict(x)[0], svr_linerar.predict(x)[0], svr_poly(x)[0]


getdata('D:\\android\\trans1.csv')


predicted_prices=predicted_price(dates,prices,10)
print(predicted_prices)
```

Here is the error that I am getting:

```
Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[19102018. 19102018. 19102018. ... 22102018. 20102018. 23102018.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Changing predicted_price:

```
(dates,prices,10)
```

to

```
([dates,prices,10])
```

Gives this error:

```
predicted_price() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'prices' and 'x'
```

Here is the image of data:

[image: date and price data]

Comment: In case you can make a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including some data, you might want to ask for feedback on [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code has at least 3 issues:

- `getdata` does not `return` anything. It only works because `dates` and `prices` are global. Move both of them in `getdata` and `return dates, prices`
- `SVR` is not imported (sklearn I guess)
- What the error message tells you: `dates = dates.reshape(-1, 1)`

### Sub-question about parameters

> Changing predicted_price:
>
> (dates,prices,10)
>   to
>
> ([dates,prices,10])
>   Gives this error:
>
> predicted_price() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'prices' and 'x'

When you write `[dates,prices,10]` you construct a single list. This single list is what you pass to the function. But the function expects 3 parameters, not one. Hence call it like `predicted_price(dates,prices,10)`.

Another note: The braces `(...)` belong to the function, not to the data. This is important, because

```
predicted_price(dates,prices,10)
```

is different from

```
predicted_price((dates,prices,10))
```

The first one is correct, the second one constructs a tuple and passes it to `predicted_price`.

In case you can make a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including some data, you might want to ask for feedback on [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)